# Datepickerdialog don't open when its empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

In the app the fields are not open by click when its empty. Its possible if the field is already filled for intance with 23-03-2017. The code give no error. Tested on different API levels. Who can help me?

```
                break;
            case InstrumentItem.S_FREEDATE:
            case InstrumentItem.S_BUYDATE:
            case InstrumentItem.S_CERTDATE:
            case InstrumentItem.S_EXPDATE:
                holder.valueLabel.setFocusable(false);
                holder.valueLabel.setOnClickListener(view ->  {
                    try {
                        showDatePickerDialog(holder.valueLabel.getText().toString(), (datePicker, year, month, day) -> {
                            String dateInFormat = getDateInFormat(year, month, day);
                            holder.valueLabel.setText(dateInFormat);
                            mItems.get(position).value = dateInFormat;

                        }).show();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                break;
```

Comment: why have you set   `holder.valueLabel.setFocusable(false);`, when you want to click it and please holder.valueLabel is a `textview` or `edittext`.

Comment: @AnchalSingh I won't be using the default keyboard by set holder.valueLabel.setFocusable(true); I want the android datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was not working, there was no date. I fixed it with the option to pick the device date (current date), the DatePickerdialog opens.

```
                        try {
                            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                            holder.valueLabel.setText(date);
                            mItems.get(position).value = date;
```